# Rails - changing whether a field is displayed or not dependent on select - not quite working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I've got a form where if the user selects "Other" from a dropdown, a field appears below saying "Other - please specify". However, it isn't quite working. If I set display:none for the "please specify" field, then when the form is saved and the user goes back in to edit it, all they see is the select box, and not the "please specify" field.

I know why this is happening - it is because the jQuery is waiting for the select box to be changed by the user before the show event fires.

However, if I remove the display:none from the CSS, then when the user first displays the form, they see the select box, and the "please specify" field, regardless of what is displayed in the select box. What can I do to fix this? I could have the "if" block of the code execute on the page load as well, but don't know how to do this? Thanks!!

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#pref_select").change(function(){
        if ($("#pref_select").val()=="Other"){
            $("#other-pref").show(500);
        } else {
            $("#other-pref").hide();
        }
    })
})
</script>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pref %><br />
  <%= f.select :pref, ["", "1", "2", "Other"], {:id => "pref_select"} %>
</div>

<div class="field" id="other-pref">
  <%= f.label "Other - please specify" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :other_pref %>
</div>
```

Comment: you can trigger the change on pageload... by adding .change() to the end of your statement.. then it will check the value everytime the page is loaded

Comment: sorry, I'm not that great with JS yet - where abouts do I need to put the extra .change()? Thanks

Comment: `$("#pref_select").change(function(){
        if ($("#pref_select").val()=="Other"){
            $("#other-pref").show(500);
        } else {
            $("#other-pref").hide();
        }
    }).change()` // <-- right at the end of your change function - before the end of the document.ready function

Comment: that's it, thanks so much! feel free to put it as an answer so i can accept :)

Comment: Your welcome.  Glad it helped you get what you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger the check on page load you to trigger the change event.  You bound the change event but your check will only occur once it's been triggered.  So to get your desired affect you need to trigger change() on page load

```
$("#pref_select").change(function() {
    if ($("#pref_select").val() == "Other") {
        $("#other-pref").show(500);
    } else {
        $("#other-pref").hide();
    }
}).change()​ // <-- this triggers the change event
```